# nodejs enable async function return value in global scope

Tags: javascript, async.js

I need to use a value returned by an asynchronous function into a get request.
This is my code:

```
let pwd;

async function getSecret() {

    const [version] = await smClient.accessSecretVersion({
        name: pgpwd
    });
    const pwd = version.payload.data.toString();
    console.log(`in  ${pwd}`);
    return pwd;
}


  promise1 =  getSecret().then((pwd) => console.log(`promise then ${pwd}`)   );
  
  console.log(promise1.then((pwd) => console.log(`promise1 ${pwd}`)));
  
  console.log(`global scope pwd ${pwd}`);

app.get('/pwd', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`get ${pwd}`);
    res.send(`pwd = ${pwd}!`);
});
```

I receive the value in promise.then but it is undefined in the global scope.

```
2020-09-20 11:27:00.909  > node index.js
2020-09-20 11:27:00.909  
2020-09-20 11:27:02.152  GET200363 B2 sPostmanRuntime/7.26.5 https://nodejs1-
2020-09-20 11:27:03.379 get undefined
2020-09-20 11:27:03.445 in 123456
2020-09-20 11:27:03.445 promise then 123456
2020-09-20 11:27:03.445 promise1 undefined
2020-09-20 11:27:04.634 get undefined
```

Comment: You're not assigning anything to `let pwd;`. So, in the `promise.then((pwd) ...)` `pwd` refers to the resolved value of the promise, not the global variable

Comment: Even if you did assign the data to `pwd` it would still be `undefined` in your route because it's asynchronous

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a global variable at all. Make your GET request callback `async` as well and `await` the result of your `getSecret` function in the callback.

If `getSecret` is an expensive function to execute then you could wrap a function around it with a closure where the `pwd` value is stored in. Then when the function is called it checks if `getSecret` has been called before and calls it. Or when it has been called before just return the result instead of calling `getSecret` again.

```
async function getSecret() {
  const [ version ] = await smClient.accessSecretVersion({
    name: pgpwd
  });
  const pwd = version.payload.data.toString();
  return pwd;
}

function storePwd() {
  let pwd = null;
  return async function() {
    if (pwd === null) {
      pwd = await getSecret();
    }
    return pwd;
  };
}

const getPwd = storePwd();

app.get('/pwd', async (req, res) => {
  const pwd = await getPwd();
  res.send(`pwd = ${pwd}!`);
});
```

Comment: But I don't want to call getSecret into every get I receive. It is very expansive. No way to save the value globally?

Comment: Sure there is. Do you need to wait for the value to be `pwd` value to be calculated before the response is sent or can it send a placeholder value like `null` if the `pwd` has not yet been calculated?

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic to this. You just need to assign it:

```
let pwd; // global

// ...

getSecret().then((localPwd) => { // renamed to something different so that we
                                 // don't shadow (hide) the global pwd 
    console.log(`promise then ${localPwd}`);
    pwd = localPwd; // assign to global variable
})
```

That's it. It's just a variable assignment. Nothing more complicated than that.

Of course, doing it this way means that in the first few milliseconds when your app starts up before `getSecret()` returns the value of the global `pwd` is still undefined. And if you happen to do a get request at this time you will get undefined. But after that it will have the value you expect. As long as you are OK with this limitation I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing.

However, if you don't want your process to answer that get request then you must not define the get request until `getSecret()` returns. Normally I would personally write code like this:

```
getSecret().then((pwd) => {

    console.log(`promise then ${pwd}`);

    // ALL other app logic such as `get` definitions
    // are done inside the promise then:

    app.get('/pwd', (req, res) => {
        console.log(`get ${pwd}`);
        res.send(`pwd = ${pwd}!`);
    });
});
```

If you don't want the `then` function to be too long you can instead encapsulate your application logic in another function. This is nothing new, C/C++ has something like this with the `main()` function:

```
let pwd;

function init () {
    app.get('/pwd', (req, res) => {
        console.log(`get ${pwd}`);
        res.send(`pwd = ${pwd}!`);
    });
}

getSecret().then((localPwd) => {

    console.log(`promise then ${localPwd}`);

    pwd = localPwd;

    init(); // start the app
});
```